# Apache Cassandra 3.10 : CQL query to check remote application connections in Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I want to know if there is a `cqlsh` query to check remote application connections in Cassandra DB, just like V$session in oracle, or processlists in mysql.

Comment: Running a `$ netstat | grep 9042` would probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a cqlsh query to do that, but you can use cassandra `java-diver` to do a manual pooling. This link: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/manual/pooling/#monitoring-and-tuning-the-pool, gives a simple example that will print the number of open connections, active requests, and maximum capacity for each host, every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there any way, if I can see the remote connection details like machine name or IP and what query he is currently running..etc ?

Comment: You can use the nodetool utility command-line interface: http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsStatus.html, for monitoring Cassandra and performing routine database operations. But if you have a datastax distribution, you can use DataStax OpsCenter which is a graphical user interface for monitoring and administering all nodes in a Cassandra cluster from one centralized console.